# Blender showing me textures even though the nodes are not linked to the principled shader

Tags: texturing

Basically what the title says. I import textures made with substance painter into blender, and as soon as I add them as a node, they show up in the viewport preview, and when I click on them it basically switches between them. For example, I click on the albedo node, it shows me the texture in the viewport. I click on the metallic node, it shows me the metallic node in the viewport, and so on. It seems like I've activated some kind of instant preview or something? Hopefully it's clear.

[image]

[image]

What's wrong?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong in the setup above. Textured shading mode is what shows preview of the texture from currently selected Image Texture node on the mesh.

Comment: ah.. I thought you still had to link the nodes to the principled shader in order for them to show up. My bad then, I guess.

Comment: You do if you want them rendered. Selecting them lets you see the texture on your object in textured viewport shading, but it won't be factored into rendering unless the nodes are connected.

Comment: alright thanks for the help